# Command line confusion when importing .jar and other .class files

Tags: java, command-line, jar, javac

I am trying to compile and run the main method in class A.  Class A imports classes from both both class B and classes contained in C.jar. These files are all located in the same folder, and the java files are located in the default package.

After trying everything single permutation of "javac" and "java" with different values of "-cp" and various orderings of the afforementioned files and their .class counterparts, I was able to run the main method successfully, but I'm left confused over why the following now works...

```
java -cp :C.jar A
```

Can somebody explain to me why there is no reference to class B whose classes are imported and used by class A?

Comment: What exactly is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If `B.class` is in the current working directory, and you were able to make it work with the command `java -cp :C.jar A`, that implies that your full java class path includes both the current working directory and the classes inside `C.jar`.

There is no need to directly mention `B` because it is already inside a directory (the working directory) on the class path.

If the working directory was not included on the class path, then Java would have a problem finding `A` as well.